# Rails says that an instantiated variable is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a quiz site. I have a class `Session`, which holds the current question and the number of questions that the person has gotten right and a controller with `start` and `next` methods.

Here is the session model:

```
class Session < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :questionNumber, :currentQuestion, :correctQuestions

    def start
        self.questionNumber = 1
        self.correctQuestions = 0
    end
end
```

And this is the sessions controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def start
        @currentSession = Session.new
        @currentSession.start
        @currentSession.currentQuestion = Question.find(@currentSession.questionNumber)
        render 'session'
    end

    def next
        @currentSession.questionNumber += 1
        @currentSession.currentQuestion = Question.find(@currentSession.questionNumber)
        render 'session'
    end
end
```

I call `start` from a link in my view, and when they answer a question, I call `next` (again from the view). I get the error: `` "undefined method `questionNumber' for nil:NilClass" ``

How do I keep `@currentSession` from being reset to `nil` between method calls? Aren't `@` variables shared in the class?

Comment: `next` is a reserved keyword. You cannot use it as a method. Are you sure that `next` is even called correctly?

Comment: Not the error you are dealing with at the moment, but you almost certainly don't want those attr_accessors

Answer (score 0):

No, instance variables are not shared between calls, they are "shared" between methods since they are a property of the object (being the controller, and yes I know the word shared is not a good term).  You can either pass an id of the session into the URL (`params[:session_id]`) or store it in `session`.

Answer (score 0):

`@variables` are instance variables, not class ones. Rails creates an instance of your controller for every request, so instance variables will not help. Also keep in mind that consequent requests may not come to the same rails worker process.

You can use rails `session` to store a few data in cookies and init your `Session` from these:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def start
        session[:current_question] = 1
        session[:correct_answers] = 0
        @currentQuestion = Question.find(session[:current_question])
        render 'session'
    end

    def next
        session[:current_question] += 1
        @currentQuestion = Question.find(session[:current_question])
        render 'session'
    end
end
```

See [rails guide for session](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#accessing-the-session)